# How to make shadow in UILabel

Tags: xcode, uilabel

Shadow of UILabel"

I have tried this code

label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);

but i am unable to get the shadow, i have searched on the internet, but none answers well.
http://tinyurl.com/au4exlo , this is a reference site, where a shadow is there under each word.

Please correct my code if am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think these are two separate UILabels displaying same values but one is inverted. Additionally, the bottom UILabel is obscured by a half transparent PNG image.

If you are not familiar with Photoshop, This might give you idea about what I mean by half transparent gradient. http://thepowerpointblog.com/media/blogs/all/10_Sept/Lance_8.jpg